# Spring-cassandra and datastax driver update

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

The latest release of spring-cassandra is dependent on the 2.1.5 datastax driver.  Is there any ETA for an update to the 2.2 release?

Answer (score 0):

there's no ETA yet, however we plan to update the Spring Data Cassandra module after the [Release Train Hopper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Hopper).